# Usage question either past tense

Tags: tenses

Which one is correct:

> I am among those who slept on the floor

or

> I was among those who slept on the floor.

Answer (score 3):

Both the sentences are correct but give different meanings. Both the sentences indicate an action which happened in the past but first sentence indicates your present relationship with those who slept on the floor and the second sentence indicates your past relationship with those who slept on the floor.

Comment: Very useful answer.